# How to Set Text of Google Signin Button and Where is the g-signin2 Class Data Attribute Documentation

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, google-identity, google-oauth-java-client

I have Web App using Google OAuth working but would like to have the sign in button say "**Sign** in with Google" whether or not the user is actually signed into Google.  By default the button says "**Signed** in with Google" when they are signed in.  Is it possible to set the text of the Google sign in button?

I thought there might be a "data-" attribute for the g-signin2 HTML class but can't seem to find documentation for it.  Where is the g-signin2 class data attribute documentation?

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-width="300" data-height="200" data-longtitle="true">
```

Comment: Does anyone know where to go for support on Google Signin?